# Can Xamarin UITest backdoors return a value on iOS?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I'm writing automated tests for a Xamarin Forms mobile app. Since it's difficult to directly interact with an embedded Google/Apple map, I wrote a few backdoor methods designed to get all the information the map would provide to a human. However, on iOS, the method I wrote doesn't provide a return value, despite my instructions to the contrary.

So far, I've done all manner of things, including reducing the method to nothing but a stub returning a dummy string. It still refuses to do it. Nowhere in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-backdoors) indicates that a value can't be returned on iOS.

```
[Export("GetUnits:")]
public NSString GetUnits(NSString val) // param unused
{
    return new NSString("TEST"); // returns this value in the app, but it doesn't ever make it to the test harness
}
```

The above code *should* return "TEST" to the test harness, which would then be printed in my REPL after I call `app.Invoke("GetUnits:", "")`, which always produces

```
[

]
```

instead of

```
[
    "TEST"
]
```

The method is named properly and called properly; error messages occur if I don't call it properly (e.g. wrong number of parameters, wrong method name) and test code inserted into the method executes fine, so I know it's executing. It's just not returning the value to the test harness. The equivalent Android version of this method works perfectly.

I found one person on the Xamarin forums with the same problem, but his topic hasn't been touched in two years. I've read every pertinent thing I can find on the web, all to no avail.

Edited for formatting. (Whoops.)

Comment: Hi , if this is an issue , you can submit in here . https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: This is not a Xamarin.Forms issue - I'll write what I know below :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we're using in our own integration tests to make sure we don't break this functionality:

This line is how we're calling the backdoor:

```
_app.Invoke("backdoorWithString:", stringArg).ToString().ShouldEqual(stringArg);
```

And in the app, the backdoor we're referencing is defined in a native app, so it's hard to compare:

```
- (NSString *) backdoorWithString:(NSString *) value {
```

I would advise changing your `Export` to the correct casing:

```
[Export("getUnits:")]
```

Also please check that this method is in your `AppDelegate.cs` file.